# How to reference and reuse a correlated sub query?

Tags: correlated-subquery

Imagine a trade table and a cds_coupon table joined on trade id; the coupon table having settlement date and settlement amount as well. The required query is to get the amount and the date of the next coupon to settle.

```
    select t.tradeId AS tradeId,
(
  select settlement_date from cds_coupon e 
  where t.tradeId=e.tradeId 
  and e.settlement_date = (select min(settlement_date) from cds_coupon ei where ei.tradeId = t.tradeId  and ei.settlement_date > sysdate )
)  AS settlement_date,
( 
  select settlement_amount from cds_coupon e 
  where t.tradeId=e.tradeId 
  and e.settlement_date = (select min(settlement_date) from cds_coupon ei where ei.tradeId = t.tradeId and ei.settlement_date > sysdate )
)  AS settlement_amount, 
   FROM Trade t
```

As can be seen the two levels of identical corelation are done twice just to grab a different field - once to grab the settlement date and once to grab the settlement amount. Hence the question - how to  reference and reuse a corelated sub query ?

Comment: Can't you convert it to a join with a subquery?

Comment: There's nothing in your query that requires joining with `Trade`; I assume this is a simplification of the actual query.

Comment: If you want the settlement details for all future coupons, should the `AND` clause use 'greater than or equal to' instead of 'equal to', e.g. `e.settlement_date >= (select min(settlement_date)`?

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server you could use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
;WITH SettlementDates ()
AS
(
    SELECT tradeId, MIN(settlement_date) as settlement_date
    FROM cds_coupon  
    WHERE settlement_date > sysdate
    GROUP BY tradeId
)

SELECT e.trade_id, e.settlement_date, e.settlement_amount
FROM cds_coupon e
JOIN SettlementDates sd 
    ON (e.trade_id = sd.trade_id)
   AND (e.settlement_date = sd.settlement_date)
```

Comment: Thx. It's better than mine but the coupon is still scanned twice once to find the aggregated value (next settlement date) and then to compare the settlement dates to the next settlement date found for equality to then grab the settlement amount.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN instead of a correlated subquery:

```
select t.tradeId, e.settlement_date, e.settlement_amount
from Trade t
join (select ei.tradeId, ei.settlement_date, ei.settlement_amount
      from cds_coupon ei
      join (select tradeId, min(settlement_date) min_date
            from cds_coupon
            where settlement_date > sysdate
            group by tradeId) emin
      on ei.tradeId = e.tradeId and ei.settlement_date = min_date) e
on t.tradeId = e.tradeId
```

The subquery is a standard idiom for finding the row containing a minimum or maximum value of a field.

Comment: Thx. It's better than mine but the coupon is still scanned twice once to find the aggregated value (next settlement date) and then to compare the settlement dates to the next settlement date found for equality to then grab the settlement amount.

Comment: If you have appropriate indexes, the second should just be an index lookup, not a table scan.

Comment: Sure, but typically there wouldn't be an index on the column being aggregated and then compared with the aggregate value; like settlment date in this case or say in another similiar example of product and sales table aggregate-and-compare as find-sales-amount-nearest-to-the-average-sale and say a related attrib sales date.

Comment: If you're going to do a query like this often enough that performance is a concern, you should add the appropriate index.